# What does the value of the pH meter mean when there aren't any hydronium ions in the substance being tested?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, ph

What does the value of the pH meter mean when there aren't any hydronium ions in the substance being tested? 
How does the pH meter show a value which fluctuates as non-aqueous solvents are being tested? I thought that the pH meter only measured hydronium ions. Is there any way that this value actually means something in terms of acidity and basicity?

Comment: Please be more specific, include the substance and solvent in question and also tell us what pH readings you are getting. If a purely hypothetical question, please edit it as such.

Comment: If you put a glass electrode into a non polar solvant, it will not give any stable values. The measured pH changes erratically form to +1.68 to -4.05, then to +2.34, then to  -0.65 or to +3.19, then to - 6.95, then to any values you may think of. It will not stay stable. Try ! You will be surprised !

Comment: It may very depend on solvent. For nonpolar solvents like n-hexane, it may wildly fluctuate, driven by random electrostatics ( I remember an old vacuum tube based pH meter in a high school we had to be 1.5-2 m away and not moving to have a steady value. I guess PVC floor did not help. ) For polar ionizable solvents like alkohols, it may get more or less stable, even if strange value without particular interpretation.

Answer (score 4):

Nowadays you have to differentiate between pH measurements with non-glass sensors and with glass sensor. In the typical pH meter with a glass sensor, there could be many things that could go wrong resulting in biased results. In general, some electrodes may be sensitive to interfering ions such as $\ce{Ag+}$. So some potential could be generated also by other ions not only hydronium ions. However, the most common thing is that you are actually reading biased measurements because you are perturbing the status of your instrument.

## Interaction of the solvent with the materials of your pHmeter

First thing you have to consider is the interaction of the solvent with the materials of your pH meter. You can easily damage some part of it or dehydrate the glass membrane of your electrode.

## Solubility of the electrolyte in the junction

Then you have to bear in mind that in your glass pHmeter there is a junction that leaks an electrolyte for forming the saline bridge if this electrolyte is not soluble in your solvent the "circuit" will not close and you will have a wrong measurement.